# how to take webdriver type code as an integer

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver

[here is the html that im trying to take a and b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx7Tx.png)

I'm trying to make automation with python and selenium. There's a math game website in which you're doing addition, subtraction, division, and multiplication. It automatically skips when you write the correct answer. I wrote a code with basics that has to take `a` and `b` make the math and writes answer but it's not working because `"a"` and `"b"` are not integers even I pick'em up from their id's. Their types are selenium web drivers so I cant addition or multiply them. I tried to fix it for 10 hours but I always made it worse how do I fix that? Here is the code below.

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 import time
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.get('url')
 driver.find_element_by_id('start').click()
 time.sleep(3)
 operator = driver.find_element_by_id('operator')
 a = driver.find_element_by_id('a')
 b = driver.find_element_by_id('b')
 answer = driver.find_element_by_id('answer')
 if operator == "+":
     driver.find_element_by_id('answer').send_keys(a + b)
 if operator == "-":
     driver.find_element_by_id('answer').send_keys(a - b)
 if operator == ":":
     driver.find_element_by_id('answer').send_keys(a / b)
 if operator == "*":
     driver.find_element_by_id('answer').send_keys(a * b)
```

Comment: if the issue is resolved mark an answer as the correct answer so people know not to try and answer again and people can find it :) Which you can do with the big tick underneath the voting on an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the text of that particular element and do the type cast.

```
 a = int(driver.find_element_by_id('a').text)
 b = int(driver.find_element_by_id('b').text)
```